# Round real and imaginary elements of numpy array with halves rounded toward zero or away from zero

Tags: python, numpy, rounding

I have a numpy array of complex numbers and need to create a new array with rounded real and imaginary parts, where the rounding at half is either toward zero or away from zero.

There are several recommendations on stackoverflow for using the `decimal` package which allow one to specify different types of rounding. For an array of complex numbers `x`, the following code worked, but was very slow:

```
    rounded_array = np.array([
        float(Decimal(x.real).quantize(0, rounding=ROUND_HALF_DOWN)) + 1j * \
        float(Decimal(x.imag).quantize(0, rounding=ROUND_HALF_DOWNs)) for x in arr])
```

What are some simple but faster alternatives to this?

The precise meanings of `ROUND_HALF_UP` and `ROUND_HALF_DOWN` are shown here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html#decimal.ROUND_HALF_UP.

To be very clear, for rounding away from zero or toward zero, for say the real parts of the complex number, I seek (notice the differences at the halves)

```
      toward zero(ROUND_HALF_DOWN) away from zero (ROUND_HALF_UP)
-4.00         -4.0                 -4.0
-3.75         -4.0                 -4.0
-3.50         -3.0                 -4.0
-3.25         -3.0                 -3.0
-3.00         -3.0                 -3.0
-2.75         -3.0                 -3.0
-2.50         -2.0                 -3.0
-2.25         -2.0                 -2.0
-2.00         -2.0                 -2.0
-1.75         -2.0                 -2.0
-1.50         -1.0                 -2.0
-1.25         -1.0                 -1.0
-1.00         -1.0                 -1.0
-0.75         -1.0                 -1.0
-0.50         -0.0                 -1.0
-0.25         -0.0                 -0.0
 0.00          0.0                  0.0
 0.25          0.0                  0.0
 0.50          0.0                  1.0
 0.75          1.0                  1.0
 1.00          1.0                  1.0
 1.25          1.0                  1.0
 1.50          1.0                  2.0
 1.75          2.0                  2.0
 2.00          2.0                  2.0
 2.25          2.0                  2.0
 2.50          2.0                  3.0
 2.75          3.0                  3.0
 3.00          3.0                  3.0
 3.25          3.0                  3.0
 3.50          3.0                  4.0
 3.75          4.0                  4.0
 4.00          4.0                  4.0
```

The accepted solution to [How to always round up a XX.5 in numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53201470/how-to-always-round-up-a-xx-5-in-numpy) is both slow and does not provide the type of rounding I'm interested in.

Comment: Add/subtract half and truncate

Comment: Is there a reason `np.fix`, `np.ceil` and `np.floor` don't do what you need?

Comment: "Please leave a comment instead of voting to close this question" is not a good thing to write. It implies that you know something is wrong with your question. Please write a question whose quality precludes the necessity for such a disclaimer, or you are likely to be closed down.

Comment: @MadPhysicist A previous version was closed down I believe because there were those who didn't understand the question.  It was my intention to have the opportunity to clarify the question first if it's unclear.

Comment: @rhz. I highly recommend you remove the disclaimer and make sure you are following site rules. Remember that people are helping you for free here. It is your job to ask a proper question, not direct their voting or closing.

Comment: @MadPhysicist, BTW, you are right.  It appears that at least for a real numbers:     if x < 0:
        return np.trunc(x - .5)
    else:
        return np.trunc(x + 0.5) works for rounding away from zero.

Comment: @MadPhysicist No problem.  Disclaimer removed.

Comment: In addition to posting here, I've provided a proper answer to the linked question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62665628/2988730.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *idea* behind the [linked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53201499/2988730) is sound, but `np.vectorize` does not really vectorize anything. Let's look at `ROUND_HALF_DOWN`, which rounds towards zero. This means that for `x >= 0`, you want to get `ceil(x - 0.5)`. For `x < 0` you want to do `floor(x + 0.5)`. This can be accomplished using a vectorized operation, e.g.

```
mask = (x >= 0)
output = x.copy()
np.add(output, -0.5, where=mask, out=output)
np.add(output, 0.5, where=~mask, out=output)
np.ceil(output, where=mask, out=output)
np.floor(output, where=~mask, out=output)
```

More space-consumingly, but less verbosely:

```
mask = (x >= 0)
output = np.empty_like(x)
output[mask] = np.ceil(x[mask] - 0.5)
output[~mask] = np.floor(x[~mask] + 0.5)
```

To do the operations in-place, just operate on `x` instead of `output`. The second part is treating the real and imaginary parts of the array separately. For contiguous arrays, this is easily done with a view, e.g.:

```
x = x.view(np.float)
```

You can convert back with

```
x = x.view(np.complex)
```

If your arrays are non-contiguous, your best bet is to process the real and imaginary components separately. `x.real` and `x.imag` are views into the data, so you can manipulate it in-place.

**TL;DR**

```
def round_half_down(arr):
    output = arr.copy().view(np.float)   # This won't fail because the copy is contiguous
    mask = (output >= 0)
    np.subtract(output, 0.5, where=mask, out=output)
    np.ceil(output, where=mask, out=output)
    np.invert(mask, out=mask)
    np.add(output, 0.5, where=mask, out=output)
    np.floor(output, where=mask, out=output)
    return output.view(np.complex)
```

Comment: @rhz. Yes, for the first part of the question I used `x`, then switched to `arr`. They both represent the array you want to work with.

Comment: sorry I meant to say that under the TL;DR, you meant to put mask = (output >= 0) rather than mask = (arr >= 0), right?

Comment: @rhz. Excellent catch. Thank you. Fixed

Comment: Note that there are some floating-point corner cases to watch out for. These may not matter to the OP. For example, if `x = 5000000000000001.0` (which is exactly representable as an IEEE 754 binary64 float) then `ceil(x - 0.5)` evaluates to `5000000000000000.0`, because `x - 0.5` is _not_ exactly representable, so is rounded, and then that rounded result is passed to the `ceil` operation. There are similar issues with `floor(x + 0.5)` for positive `x` (e.g., it rounds `0.49999999999999994` to `1.0`).

Comment: @MarkDickinson. Those are excellent points. The goal is to set up OP to handle this in a vectorized manner. You can add bulk special case handling by adding a mask for `|x| > 499999....9` (or whatever the actual threshold is for the number always being an integer is), and a mask for numbers whose difference from the nearest odd multiple of 0.5 is within 1e-15 or so. I suspect that even operations like that will be cheaper than using `np.vectorize`, and hopefully OP can figure out how to do them now.