# Python - how to round up to specified decimal

Tags: python, numpy, rounding

I want to round up numbers in Python to a specified decimal.

For example, if I choose

```
(2.1, 0.2) -->  I want to get 2.2 
(2.2, 0.2) -->  I want to get 2.2 
(3.6, 0.5) -->  I want to get 4.0
(3.5, 0.5) -->  I want to get 3.5
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Round integers to the nearest 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3348825/round-integers-to-the-nearest-10)

Comment: Are you sure about your third output? I expect it to be 3.5

Comment: @mathfux I suppose that the second value is the threshold on which he\she decide to round up. 3.6 - 3 = 0.6 > 0.5.

Comment: @mathfux check my solution

Comment: @Nikaido It's not mentioned in a question. It could be in a different way: `rounder(x, y)` is some multiple of `y` that is closest to `x`. If there are two such multiples, choose the one that has a higher absolute value.

Comment: @mathfux, yeah, you are right. I based my answer on the output btw

Comment: My guess is: if the floating part of the number is <= of the rounding number, then cap the value to that float, else get the ceiling

Comment: It's a bad idea to guess smth at all. Every question should be [well defined](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-defined). If it's not, you need to point out what are different ways to interpret it.

Comment: @mathfux, Yeah I agree on that. Unfortunately every one here has answered assuming what the user wanted

Answer (score 2):

probably not the most efficient, but working with numpy

**I am assuming that you are working with not too much decimals**

```
import numpy as np 

def rounder(num, round_):
   int_p = np.floor(num)
   float_p = num - int_p
   print(float_p) # this print is meant to show the floating point problem
   diff  = float_p - round_
   if diff <= 0 or -0.00001 <diff< 0.00001:
       return int_p + round_
   else:
       return np.ceil(num)

 list_ = [(2.1, 0.2), (2.2, 0.2), (3.6, 0.5), (3.5, 0.5)]

 for num, round_ in list_:
     print("({}, {})".format(num, round_), rounder(num, round_))

 
 # (2.1, 0.2) 2.2
 # (2.2, 0.2) 2.2
 # (3.6, 0.5) 4.0
 # (3.5, 0.5) 3.5
```

unfortunately there are problems with the representation of the floating point that is not so precise. That's the reason why I wrote another condition in the if else  `-0.00001 <diff< 0.00001` that means, if the difference is not so high (near zero) than it is basically zero

New algorithm as requested from op

```
import numpy as np 

def rounder(num, round_):
  int_p = np.floor(num)
  new_value = int_p
  while new_value < num:
    new_value = round(new_value + round_, 4)
  return new_value


list_ = [(2.1, 0.2), (2.2, 0.2), (3.6, 0.5), (3.5, 0.5), (0.178, 0.1)]

for num, round_ in list_:
    print("({}, {})".format(num, round_), rounder(num, round_))


# (2.1, 0.2) 2.2
# (2.2, 0.2) 2.2
# (3.6, 0.5) 4.0
# (3.5, 0.5) 3.5
# (0.178, 0.1) 0.2
```

Comment: After a second check it doesn't give the right result for: `print(rounder(0.178,0.1))` which should give 0.2 but gives 1.0

Comment: @Jeroen let me check a sec

Comment: @Jeroen then I am not understanding what you want exactly. In your example, for the value (3.6, 0.5) why do you get 4?

Comment: for what I did understand, for the value (0.178, 0.1) I should get 1

Comment: For (3.6, 0.5) I indeed want to have (4.0). It is rounded up the next value as a multiplication of 0.5. Then For (0.178, 0.1) we have possible candidates (0,0.1,0.2,0.3) --> so this would be 0.2. Only when the number is equal to a multiplication of r ound_, I want to maintain the number

Comment: @Jeroen check it now

Comment: Sorry if I am not clear, but if I use (9.3, 0.4) I get 9.4, where I expect 9.6. The closest multiplications of 0.4 with an integer to 9.3 are 9.2 and 9.6. The upper limit is 9.6. Only when the upper limit is exactly the original number, I want to return the original number.

Answer (score 0):

What I wanted was:

```
def rounder(num, round_):
    val = num // round_   
    if val*round_  == num:
        return num
    else:
        return val*round_ + round_ 
    
list_ = [(9.3, 0.4), (2.2, 0.2), (3.6, 0.5), (3.5, 0.5), (0.178, 0.1)]

for num, round_ in list_:
    print("({}, {})".format(num, round_), rounder(num, round_))
```

Answer (score -1):

Assume that `rounder(x, y)` is some multiple of y that is closest to x. If there are two such multiples, choose the one that has a higher absolute value.

Python has an issue of rounding halves:

```
>>> round(10.5)
10
>>> np.round(10.5)
10.0
```

#### Iterable case

Borrowing from [this simple fix](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53201499/3044825), I'll extend it for OP's question

```
import math
def rounder(x, y):
    r = x/y
    if (r - int(r) >= 0.5):
        return y * math.ceil(r)
    else:
        return y * math.floor(r)
```

Sample run:

```
>>> rounder(2.1, 0.2)
2.2
>>> rounder(2.2, 0.2)
2.2
>>> rounder(3.6, 0.5)
3.5
>>> rounder(3.5, 0.5)
3.5
```

This is designed to call it multiple times on items, usually in a process of some iterations.

#### Vectorised case

It's also possible to rewrite it in order to work in vectorised way:

```
def rounder(x, y):
    r = x/y
    np.where(r-r//1 >= 0.5, y * np.ceil(r), y * np.floor(r))

>>> rounder(np.array([2.1,2.2,3.6,3.5]), np.array([0.2, 0.2, 0.5, 0.5]))
array([2.2, 2.2, 3.5, 3.5])
```

Comment: rounder(3.6, 0.5) should give me 4.0, where it is 3.5 according to your function.

Comment: I added the solution below